# Python pandas fill missing value (NaN) based on condition of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have figured out how to fill the NaN values with the previous cell by using `df.fillna(method='ffill')`.

However, I am not sure how to base it on a condition that if the country name differs from the country name in its previous cell, then the total case cell value should be 0, otherwise replace `NaN` with the previous cell's total case value.

Comment: please provide sample data in text format instead of image.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani Sorry, it is my first time using StackOverflow, I had trouble trying to upload in text format. I will see if I can figure out how to upload it in text format. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) will give the wanted result. `columns` here are all the columns you want to apply the missing value logic to.

```
columns = ['total_cases', 'total_deaths', ...]
df[columns] = df.groupby('location')[columns].fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)
```

Note that you need to apply `fillna` twice, once with forward fill and once with a constant 0 to fill all nan values. This is to make sure that any nans that starts in a new group are filled with 0.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I've just given it a go, however, it did not seem to replace any of the nan values.

Comment: @Ava: You need to assign it back to `df` as well, `df = df.groupby('location').fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0)`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to assign it back. However, the grouping column "location" disappeared. So I tried doing this: df = df.groupby('location', as_index=False).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0). But when I tried to plot it in wingIDE it was not picking up the location column, however Spyder was picking it up. Do you know if there is another way to keep the "location" column? Many Thanks.

Comment: @Ava: You are correct, I updated the answer. The idea is to overwrite the updated columns in the original dataframe. This will keep all other columns, e.g. `location`.